# Using ladda javascript before posting form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use this script for my login form submit button, but it's not working at all...

Script: http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/

Basically, i wan't to be able to show the loading indicator onclick and before it submits. Do any of you guys know how to do this ?.

Comment: can you tell us more details ? probably console.log errors, warning or even jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the [README.md at Github](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda)? Try to follow the instructions and get back with specifics if you should not manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the submiting form (im gona use coffeescript but you can transform it to its jquery javascript equivalent)

```
$("myform").on "submit" , (e)->
  e.preventDefault()
  data = $("myform").serialize()
  ladda = Ladda.create($(@).find("submit-button")[0])  
  // in the version i use i have to use [0] because the ladda does not accept a jquery object, it needs a dom object
  ladda.start() //this starts the animation
  $.post("path/for/post",
    data: data
  ).always ->
    ladda.stop() //this stops the animation on any case fail or success
```